# App crashes when react-native-maps and react-native-geolocation-service modules are installed together

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

**Bug**

react-native-maps does not work with react-native-geolocation-service module in the same project. App crashes on load. Once react-native-geolocation-service module is removed from the project, the app works fine.

react-native-geolocation-service is needed to get the users location, because it is more accurate than the javascript navigator object.

https://bitbucket.org/mihailiviu/react-native-maps-geolocation/src/master/

**Environment info**

System:

OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory: 7.14 GB / 15.95 GB
Binaries:
Node: 12.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 6.13.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
SDKs:
Android SDK:
API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
Build Tools: 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 23.0.3, 26.0.1, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
System Images: android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version 3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5

**Library version**

react-native-maps => 0.26.1
react-native-geolocation-service => ^4.0.0

**Steps To Reproduce**

Sample app provided below which shows that the 2 modules don't work together as expected:

Download the sample app below, install dependencies, and try to run it.
https://bitbucket.org/mihailiviu/react-native-maps-geolocation/src/master/

npm install
npm run android

**Describe what you expected to happen:**

App will crash on load.
Reproducible sample code
https://bitbucket.org/mihailiviu/react-native-maps-geolocation/src/master/

EDIT:

This is what I pulled from logkitty:

```
$ react-native log-android
info Starting logkitty
[13:36:06] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[13:36:07] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge.

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
                           └ CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()

[13:36:12] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()

[13:36:13] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()

[13:36:21] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.ctor()

[13:36:21] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
                           └ ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge.

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()

[13:36:26] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()

[13:36:27] D | ReactNative ▶︎ ReactInstanceManager.detachViewFromInstance()
```

Comment: Hi Mike, please also leave any tracebacks / errors you might have in the logs.

Comment: I had used both these libraries in my project and its working fine. So, this is not the issue that both won't work together in same project.

Comment: Maybe the new versions of these libraries?